# Deploy two asp.net mvc projects in the same azure VM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web-deployment

I have two asp.net mvc projects (one for the back office and the other for the front office). I want to deploy them on the same virtual machine with different URLs : For example the first with the url "myProject" and the second with url "myProject/Front".
If i deploy them under the same folder wwwroot, i have conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

With an Azure VM you have a full Windows Server at your disposal. Just RDP into your VM and manage the sites with IIS as you would more traditional websites. You can't technically deploy multiple applications to the same document root, but you can set one up as a virtual application for the other. However, bear in mind that the Web.config of the outermost application will apply to any virtual application residing within. Otherwise, just create two entirely distinct sites in IIS each with their own document root.